# Como passo o endereço do primeiro char de uma string para uma função escrever nele?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, memória, malloc

O problema é o seguinte: Fiz uma função que pega a saída de determinado comando do SO e armazena em uma string. A ideia agora seria declarar uma string de apenas um char na minha função main usando `malloc`, chamar a minha função passando o comando que quero pegar a saída e passando também o endereço do byte que foi alocado para o meu char. A partir disso, eu iria ir expandindo a minha string de inicialmente 1 char usando o `realloc` dentro da outra função para armazenar os valores que o `fscanf` retornar diretamente nesses espaços.

Como isso poderia ser feito?

Exemplo do código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int SystemGetOut_char();


int main()
{
    char *teste = malloc(1);
    char command[] = "ls";
    SystemGetOut_char(command, &teste);
    return 0;
}


int SystemGetOut_char(char *command, char *output) 
{
    int chunk = 1;
    FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");
    int charnumber = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%c", &output[charnumber]) != EOF)
    {
        chunk++;
        output = realloc(output, chunk);
        charnumber++;
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

OBS: Sei que o código não vai funcionar, é só para terem uma ideia da estrutura.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade o código que tem está bem perto de ficar a funcionar, precisando apenas de poucos ajustes.

Você já está a passar o endereço da `string` para a função `SystemGetOut_char`:

```
SystemGetOut_char(command, &teste);
//                     ----^
```

Que lhe irá permitir alterar a `string` dentro da função, no entanto o tipo especificado no parâmetro da função não está correto:

```
int SystemGetOut_char(char *command, char *output) 
//                                --------^
```

Pode pensar em termos genéricos. Se tem um `char*` e passa o seu endereço, então fica com um `char**` que deveria ser exatamente esse o tipo do segundo parametro. Isso significa que a sua função tem que passar a lidar com um duplo ponteiro, e com as alterações que isso implica no resto das operações.

A sua função com essas alterações fica assim:

```
int SystemGetOut_char(char *command, char **output){
//          agora duplo ponteiro  --------^

    int chunk = 1;
    FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");
    int charnumber = 0;

    //aqui a posição de memoria onde guarda o char é dada por *output + charnumber
    while(fscanf(fp, "%c", *output + charnumber) == 1)
    {
        chunk++;
        *output = realloc(*output, chunk); //aqui com *output para ser o apontado
        charnumber++;
    }
    (*output)[charnumber] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador no fim

    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note que troquei a condição no `while` para `while (fscanf(...) == 1)`. O [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) devolve a quantidade de elementos que consegue atribuir, e quando neste caso não conseguir atribuir `1` significa que chegou ao fim e deve parar.

Também não tive que guardar espaço para o terminador porque a string já vinha com um espaço disponível, logo tem sempre 1 a mais do que precisa, podendo esse caratere a mais ser usado para o terminador.

Como a `string` foi alterada já dentro da função, basta mostrar normalmente no `main`:

```
int main()
{
    char *teste = malloc(1);
    char command[] = "ls";
    SystemGetOut_char(command, &teste);
    printf("%s", teste); // <----
    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo de execução para o comando `ls` que você tem no código, na minha maquina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta foi ótima. Muito obrigado.